# asp.net mvc 3 mixing jquery and razor to get and set the image width

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am trying to specifically set an image inline width attribute to it's value, so I am trying to do that with jquery and razor, but I keep getting the initialized value - 100;

Code:

```
 @{
 var width = "100";
 }


     <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {

        $('.tab-item-photo img').each(function () {
            width = $(this).width();
            alert(width);
        });


     });

     </script>


 <div class="tab-item-photo"><img src="@Url.Content("~/_files/149471/images/1712frnt.JPG")" width="@width" height="140px" /></div>
```

EDIT:

If I could do something like this:

```
<div class="tab-item-photo"><img src="@Url.Content("~/_files/149471/images/1712frnt.JPG")"
width="$(this).width()" height="140px" /></div>
```

it would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want something like:

```
 @{
   //var width = "100"; not needed
 }

     <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () 
     {
        $('.tab-item-photo img').each(function()
        {
          var img = new Image();
          img.src = $(this).attr("src");
          $(this).attr("width", img.width);
        });
     });
```

```
     <div class="tab-item-photo">
       <img src="@Url.Content("~/_files/149471/images/1712frnt.JPG")" 
            width="1" height="1" /></div>
```

Comment: Thing is, it has to be inline.

Comment: Well I'm a bit confused, you set the value of the image inline to 100, then you try to set all of them to they're own width, nothing is going to change.  Is there something else that is changing the width and you want to change it back?

Comment: no. The images are being load dynamically, and I have to specify for each image its width in the inline width="" attribute. I can't do it with jquerty attr() though because in the actual source code it has to say width="".

Comment: How/When are the images loaded "dynamically"?  In the View or using JQuery?

Comment: In the View. if I could do something like this, it would work.    `<div class="tab-item-photo"><img src="@Url.Content("~/_files/149471/images/1712frnt.JPG")"
width="$(this).width()" height="140px" /></div>
`

Comment: so why doesn't `width="@width"` solve the problem?  Or are you trying to set the width to the actual width of the image downloaded?

Comment: I am trying to have the width attribute state the current width of the image

Comment: Some how i'm not communicating with you.  It sounds like you want the width of the image stored on disk.  IF this is the case, why specify a width at all?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3110/discussion-between-erik-philips-and-bobek)

Answer (score 0):

try `$(this).attr('width');` to get attribute value.

`.width()` are using offcetWidth property of element, not attribute. Maybe it should be image loaded but on `$(document).ready()` it's still not.

EDIT:

Maybe you need to bind image load event and change the width:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".tab-item-photo img").load(function () {
        $(this).attr('width', $(this).width());
    });
});
```